vcard will not download on android device
I am implementing a vcard where users can add to contact with all the information populated. I am currently using this package: jeroendesloovere/card (https://github.com/jeroendesloovere/vcard).
When testing my implementation, it works perfectly on IOS device as it immediately opens the preview window for adding a contact, but for android devices it does not work. It just navigates to another url browser saying this site cannot be reached. I am not sure if this is android behavior where it could not detect a vcf file. I am not sure if there is a workaround to make it automatically open the contact preview on android like how it be on IOS.
my code:
public function download($vcard_data)
    {

        $vcard = new VCard();

        $lastname = '';
        $firstname = '';
        $additional = '';
        $prefix = '';
        $suffix = '';

        
        foreach ($vcard_data->phoneNumbers as $phoneNumber) {
            $type = "TYPE={$phoneNumber->type}";
            $vcard->addPhoneNumber($phoneNumber->phoneNumber, $type);
        }

        foreach ($vcard_data->emails as $email) {
            $type = "TYPE={$email->type}";
            $vcard->addEmail($email->address, $type);
        }

        foreach ($vcard_data->socialMedias as $socialMedia) {
            $type = "TYPE={$socialMedia->type}";

            $vcard->addURL($socialMedia->link, $type);
        }

        $vcard->addName('', $vcard_data->name);

        $vcard->addCompany($vcard_data->companyName);
        $vcard->addJobtitle($vcard_data->designation);
        $vcard->addURL($vcard_data->companyWebsite, 'WORK');

        $vcard->addPhoto($vcard_data->photoUrl);

        //return $vcard->getOutput();
        return $vcard->download();
    }
}

I tried adding header to specify the content disposition as attachment like :
....
        
        $vcardOutput = $vcard->getOutput();

        // Set headers for downloading vCard
        header('Content-Type: text/vcard');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="contact.vcf"');
        echo $vcardOutput;
        exit;
        
    }

Unfortunately it does not work as well. I just want it to trigger contact app to open and preview like IOS but just couldn't figure out a solution.
Has anyone encounter this issue and know how to fix it?
